# Is there a way to force an auto-generated file to be committed along with the rest of the commit that triggers its generation?

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook

I use a simple test framework which converts contents of an *.xlsx file into a selenium browser test. This allows a high level of abstraction but is annoying to work in git due to it being a binary.

The format of the excel test file is:

```
Column A         -> Action
Column B         -> Identity (which text field, etc)
Column C onwards -> Value
```

I wrote the following code which successfully converts the excel file into a text file (*.json), essentially just a list of lists (so that order is maintained and no extra keywords are introduced).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
This script takes a GUI test in xlsx format and outputs a text interpretation.
"""

import argparse
import json
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter


def main(xlsx_test):
    ws = load_workbook(filename=xlsx_test, data_only=True).active
    col_size = len(ws.column_dimensions)
    row_size = len(ws.row_dimensions)
    full_document = []

    for col in xrange(2, col_size):
        col_letter = get_column_letter(col + 1)
        test_document = []

        for row in xrange(row_size):
            cell_reference = col_letter + str(row + 1)
            cell_value = ws[cell_reference].value

            if cell_value:
                action = ws['A' + str(row + 1)].value
                identity = ws['B' + str(row + 1)].value

                if not action:
                    action = ""
                if not identity:
                    identity = ""

                test_item = [action, identity, cell_value]
                test_document.append(test_item)
        if test_document:
            full_document.append(test_document)

    with open(xlsx_test + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(full_document, outfile, indent=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Generate text verion of tests')
    test_file = parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='the file to generate text version of tests from'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.input is None:
        print '''No file selected'''
    else:
        main(args.input)
```

To run it, I would execute the following in a bash script:

```
python /path/to/this/script.py --input='/path/to/test.xlsx'
```

I would like the text file it produces to be committed along with the xlsx binary just so that we get a git change history.

I have been reading about pre-commit hooks (something I am happy to set up on each of the contributor's machine, but I am struggling to establish whether it will include an extra generated file into the commit or not. Any direction would be great as I am not really sure what to try at the moment.

I also have to work out whether I can iterate over the list of files in the commit with extension *.xlsx and pass in the path as an argument to the python script above, in a loop. Is what I am asking doable in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a satisfactory solution. I created two commit hooks.

A pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
touch .commit
exit
```

And a post-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e .commit ]
    then
    rm .commit
    git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | while read i; do
        if [[ "${i}" == *.xlsx ]]; then
            echo
            echo ➤ Found an Excel file: $(basename "${i}") in the git diff-tree
            if [ ! -f "${i}" ]; then
                echo ➤ $(basename "${i}") was deleted. Not generating a text interpretation
                if [ -f "${i}.json" ]; then
                    echo ➤ Found an orphaned text interpretation: $(basename "${i}").json
                    rm "${i}.json"
                    echo ➤ Removed $(basename "${i}").json
                    git rm -q "${i}.json"
                    echo ➤ Removed reference to $(basename "${i}").json from git
                fi
            else
                python "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/../../relative/path/to/script.py" --input="$(pwd)/${i}"
                echo ➤ Generated text interpretation: $(basename "${i}").json
                git add "${i}.json"
                echo ➤ Added $(basename "${i}").json to git
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify
    echo ➤ Ammended commit above ⬏
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo ➤ Initial commit below  ⬎
fi
exit
```

1. Currently I can see an additional problem, to do with committing an added/modified file. A contributor will only be able to commit from the base directory of the repository.

I will update with changes once I work them out.